# Scriptlet does not work in JSP and Tomcat throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.login_jsp

Tags: jsp, tomcat, classnotfoundexception

I am a beginner in the development of Java-Web applications. I put a **scriptlet **in my login.jsp. I save the file and tried to deploy it. But it did not work.

Here is my **scriptlet:**

Eclipse IDE 2023-6

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>                               
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Yahoo from JSP !!!</title>
</head>

<% System.out.println("Test"); %>

<body>
Test <br>
My first JSP ${name}
</body>
</html>
```

I go on run as, Maven build, tomcat7:run

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] [1m--------------< [0;36mcom.in28minutes:in28Minutes-first-webapp[0;1m >--------------[m
[INFO] [1mBuilding in28Minutes-first-webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT[m
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] [1m--------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------[m
[INFO] 
[INFO] [1m>>> [0;32mtomcat7:2.2:run[m [1m(default-cli)[0;1m > [0;1mprocess-classes[m @ [36min28Minutes-first-webapp[0;1m >>>[m
[INFO] 
[INFO] [1m--- [0;32mresources:3.3.0:resources[m [1m(default-resources)[m @ [36min28Minutes-first-webapp[0;1m ---[m
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] [1m--- [0;32mcompiler:3.11.0:compile[m [1m(default-compile)[m @ [36min28Minutes-first-webapp[0;1m ---[m
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] [1m<<< [0;32mtomcat7:2.2:run[m [1m(default-cli)[0;1m < [0;1mprocess-classes[m @ [36min28Minutes-first-webapp[0;1m <<<[m
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] [1m--- [0;32mtomcat7:2.2:run[m [1m(default-cli)[m @ [36min28Minutes-first-webapp[0;1m ---[m
[WARNING] [1;33mParameter '[0;1;33mlocal[0;1;33m'[0;1;33m [0;1;33mis deprecated core expression; Avoid use of ArtifactRepository type. If you need access to local repository, switch to '${repositorySystemSession}' expression and get LRM from it instead.[m
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/
[INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at C:\Users\Olive\eclipse_JEE_testen\first-web-application3\target\tomcat
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath: 
Aug. 31, 2023 1:41:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug. 31, 2023 1:41:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting service Tomcat
Aug. 31, 2023 1:41:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Aug. 31, 2023 1:41:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

So far it works. Then I go to the browser and type in "localhost:8080"

Then I got the following error message:

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.login_jsp
type Exception report

message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.login_jsp

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.login_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:177)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    com.in28minutes.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:40)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.login_jsp
    java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    com.in28minutes.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:40)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.
```

Here is also my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.in28minutes</groupId>
    <artifactId>in28Minutes-first-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.11.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>/</path>
                        <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can anyone help me please to solve this issue?
Kind regards